# IE8: List Box border shows extra grey line in Table

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer-8

I know that ListBox will render a thin grey line in IE8 so I tried to solve the problem by putting it in a table.

I set the listbox to 100% height and width  but when it display, it doesn't take up the entire  table cell..

it only take up the entire width but for the height it doesn't take up fully but has a thin grey line just above the table bottom border.

I had use F12 to examine the ListBox but I can't find the problem.

The listbox is actually icefaces : ice:selectOneListbox

PS. The table is use to render the header for the listbox with boxing.